# Get repeated data based on condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have table like that

If I want to get repeated ids in table but only ids repeated in same catalogid for specific number of catalog like number 3

so in my example id I want to get ids repeated in ( 3 ) number of catalogid or more and have the same catalogid it will be 1,2 only

[image]

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of what you want returned from that sample table.  Your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: my result should be 1,2 only that what i want to return as the two are repeated together in same catalogeid

Comment: What if a third id is repeated 3 times with ID1, but not with ID2? should it appear in the results?

Comment: When I asked for an example, I meant exactly the same thing as you have in the question.  A table with the columns and data you want to see.

Comment: @TTeeple, I think I got him. He want IDS 1 and 2 as a result because 1 and 2 are repeating 3 time together in 3 different groups. This seems hard  enought to me. More I don't think it is doable with sql code...

Comment: @giorginakeuri yes that's exactly what i mean
and if it's hard with sql could i make it with linq in c#

Comment: @user2280862, I suspect you will not be able to do this with only linq query. But I can be wrong. I think you will have to do some calculations, combinatoric algorithms...

Comment: It can be done with SQL, if he can ever fully define the logic of what he wants.

Comment: @TabAlleman, how can you say that it can be done when you even don't understand what he wants. He wants all groups-combinations of ids which are repeating in minimum of N different catalogue. So the answer may be collection of groups like {1, 2} : 3 times, {2, 3, 4} : 5 times etc...

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri if you're right about his desired output, then it's relatively easy to do in SQL, although it won't perform particularly well since it will involve a cross join of the entire table to itself.

Comment: @TabAlleman, here is a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a703
As you can see you shoud output: `{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {6, 7}` as all those 3 combinations occur in 3 different catalogues. Can you show the easy select statement?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri would you care to post it as a new question?   I'm done with this question until the original poster makes it clearer.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri but u should take into consideration that ids and catalogeid are identity together so ids will never repeated for same catalogeid

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT IDS
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY IDS
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
```

Comment: I suspect the actual solution would be `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3` since the question states that for 3 both 1 and 2 should be returned, and 1 is repeated 4 times. Although the question is pretty difficult to understand, so I can't be too sure.

Comment: Good point, he might actually mean "three or more" instead of "exactly three".

Comment: yes i mean three or more but the trick that they repeated with same catalogeid

Comment: @user2280862 I don't understand that sentence.   What do you mean "repeated with same catalogeid"?

Comment: as 1 may be repeated 3 times and 2 repeated also 3 times but each one is repeated in different catalogeid i want the 3 times that ids repeated with same catalogeid so grouping together